# Storing methods to execute all one after the other

Tags: c#, ssh.net

I am working with SSH.NET and I want to create "Secure mode" in my `Connection` class. Basically, it should store all methods done within one connection and then "execute" them one after another when desired. Something like this:

```
Connection conn = new Connection("server", "username", "password");
conn.secureMode(true); //enabling secure mode
conn.changeDirectory("directory");
conn.downloadFile("file");
conn.FlushMethods();
conn.disconnect();
```

After `Flush()` both `changeDirectory("directory")` and `downloadFile("file")` should be "executed" in this order.

So I should store these methods in some sort of array or queue, right? But how? And then how to execute them?

Could you give me any hints?

Comment: is there some additional reason you'd like to use a queue? so far if they appear in code in this order then they will be run in the same order.

Comment: No, there is none. I was just thinking about some sort of a Collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Internally you can store a list of the commands as a series of actions inside your class and only run this list when you want to "flush" the commands.

```
 public class Connection
 {
     private List<Action> _commandList = new List<Action>();

     public void ChangeDirectory(string directoryName)
     {
         _commandList.Add(() => 
             {
             //Actual code to change directory
             });
     }

     public void FlushMethods()
     {
         foreach(var command in _commandList)
         {
             command();
         }
         _commandList.Clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: OP: Be aware of potential exceptions, you should handle them appropiately.

Comment: Correct, you will need to handle any errors at the foreach loop level or directly in the "action".

Comment: Thank you all very much!